# 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSCOREE.lib'`

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, clr, linker-errors

i keep getting this error

`1>Main.obj : MSIL module encountered; incremental linking is disabled for MSIL; performing full link
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSCOREE.lib'`

i have two phase disabled and i am using cli and clr on visual studio.
I do not have any other code in the program aswell.
this is c++ btw

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/138212/lnk1104-cannot-open-file-mscoreelib.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Install .net sdk https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks
2. Add to the system environment depens on your .net version

> ```
> NETFXKitsDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\
> NETFXSDKDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\
> ```

or to the project's libs

> ```
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\Lib\um\x86 or x64 or arm
> ```